# Command php bin\behat doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, symfony, behat

Hello I am trying to use command

```
php bin\behat
```

it's not working the result is

```
SRC_DIR=`pwd`
cd `dirname "$0"`
cd "../vendor/behat/behat/bin"
BIN_TARGET=`pwd`/behat
cd $SRC_DIR
$BIN_TARGET "$@"
```

I have to use command

```
php vendor\behat\behat\bin\behat
```

and behat is working. Somebody knows solution to this problem?
I also ask this question here: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=45834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `bin/behat` is `bash` but does not contain any shebang.

It does not contain any `php` start tag either, that means when you run the command from `php` it is treated like plain text.

Since you tagged your question with `windows-7` you will need to rewrite it in a Windows-7 compatible batch script (Powershell or something).

The given bash script do nothing but give you a shortcut to run `behat`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got stuck at same.
Here is the solution:
First use: `behat --init`

This will create your feature folder.
Once done run the following command to execute your tests:

```
bin\behat
```